# Why model expected value is computed using a model with input features?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, intercept

This post is kind of related to these two posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569843/why-shap-base-expected-value-is-0-5-for-all-my-instances) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569199/what-is-the-use-of-expected-value-in-machine-learning-models)

I learnt that model expected value (average prediction) is nothing but performance of the model when all input features are absent.

But I see that this expected value is calculated from a model with input features (whose values are not zero). But it is interpreted as model's simplest performance when X is not present.

I find this difficult to understand. Because, we compute `mean(y_pred)` from a model that we build using X input features (and their values are not zero).You can refer the code sample from this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569843/why-shap-base-expected-value-is-0-5-for-all-my-instances) where the average is computed using `mean(y_pred)`. And this is how SHAP package does it as well.

we are **taking average from a model which has non-zero values for all predictors**? Can I know why is it done this way?

I see that in SHAP average/expected values are calculated this way only,

Can you help me understand why is it done this way?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean, especially since the two linked questions seem to be completely unrelated. Could you try to clarify? Maybe you could use an example? What do you mean by "performance" of the model? The unclear part is also that you are talking about "expected value at X=0 with X != 0" what doesn't make any sense at all. The linked threads didn't make any of the claims that you mention.

Comment: Those threads were created by me as well. Those threads talk about what is expected value and how it is calculated. In this thread, based on what I learnt from other thread (especially SHAP post), you can see that the average prediction is computed based on average of `y_pred`. Do I make sense till here? before I go on to explain further?

Comment: @Tim - I removed model performance part from the post. Hope it provides improved clarity now

Comment: By X = 0- i mean all input features' value is 0. For the model that we build X not equal 0 (because they have non-zero values for all features)

Comment: Features cannot be at the same time 0 and not 0... Neither of the answers you refer to makes such claims as mentioned by your question...

Comment: No. We compute average of predictions from a model with X !=0. But when we interpret them, we call that as average prediction/expected value when X = 0. If you look at the code in the answer for SHAP post, you will know that

Comment: And my question is exactly on the interpretation part. Even am confused as to why it is being considered as average prediction when X=0 (when in fact we used all X to compute average prediction).

Comment: *"I learnt that model expected value (average prediction) is nothing but performance of the model when all input features are 0."* This sentence is unclear. Where did you learn this? The definition of 'model expected value' is completely unclear at this point.

Comment: *"But I see that this expected value is calculated from a model with input features (whose values are not zero). But it is interpreted as model's simplest performance when X=0."* Where do you see this? Explain. Where does this viewpoint come from. Why do you consider $X=0$? It is unclear why you consider this.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus - I was of the understanding that absence of features, mean X=0. Might be I misunderstood. I read this from this post here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569199/what-is-the-use-of-expected-value-in-machine-learning-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the SHAP paper does not mention features being all zeros, but "would be predicted if we did not know any features" and that is not the same. It would be the same for linear regression where if in

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \dots + \beta_k X_k + \varepsilon
$$

you would set $X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X_k = 0$, the only thing that would remain is $\beta_0$, it would just predict the "average" $y$ value. It wouldn't necessarily be true for other models, but the [SHAP paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07874) mentions this by noticing that "most models cannot handle arbitrary patterns of missing input
values".

Why does averaging the predictions tell you about the performance of the model as if the features were unknown? The details are given in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07874), but for intuition, you can think of it as integrating out the features. If your model $f$ approximates the conditional expectation

$$
E[y|X] = f(X)
$$

then by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), we know that

$$
E[y] = E[E[y|X]] = \int_X E[y|X] \,dP
$$

So if you average over the features, you are left with the marginal prediction. If you average over the features, it is like you didn't use the features. Of course, this is just an approximation, because the $X's$ you observed in the data are not necessarily representative of the whole distribution of $X$'s, but we make the assumption that our data is representative every time we use machine learning.

Comment: Thanks for your help. upvoted. I am no expert in stats. But in your response, when you mention `you would set X1=X2=⋯=Xk=0` ,  Is it incorrect to call this as X=0?

Comment: I am asking only to correct my mistake and improve

Comment: @TheGreat it's just a matter of notation, but you could write it like this. But as said, using zeroes there would work for linear models and not necessarily for other models.

Comment: Okay, is it incorrect to consider absence of features as X=0? When we don't know the value for our features, based on your understanding of the SHAP paper, what do you think it considers as value for X?

Comment: @TheGreat if you have a binary feature X where males are coded as 1, then X=0 means "female" not "absence of sex". So it is not the same.

Comment: So, let's say my model's average prediction is 0.5 (in absence of features). We say this,  based on law of total expectation- Meaning, we approximate that based on a model (in presence of features) and computed the average (and think it will match/represent the average model prediction). And SHAP tells us that without feature, we can get a mean prediction of 0.5 and if we add our features, we get a prediction of 0.5 + sum(of feature impacts). Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: @TheGreat no and 0.5 value has nothing to do with the feature being unknown. It is not about averaging the features, but the predictions. If averaging the features would be enough, we wouldn't need things like SHAP.

Comment: Yes, we average the predictions like you say and we call that average prediction value as model's average prediction in the absence of features. Am i right? So, does getting average prediction as 0.5 or 0.8 or o.3 indicate anything about the model? Is there any inference that we can make about the model's average prediction?

Comment: @TheGreat it is what the model predicts “on average”, not much more.

Comment: @TheGreat sounds like another question, not a comment.

Comment: Hi Tim, I created a new post. linked it here. Would like to have your inputs if you have time. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570084/model-average-prediction-usefulness-and-interpretation

Answer (score 2):

> I was of the understanding that absence of features, mean X=0.

The SHapley Additive Explanations (SHAP) expresses the difference in the prediction of some value, when the $X_i$ is known in comparison to when the $X_i$ is not known.

Not knowing the feature is *different* from the absence of the feature.

The 'absence of features' or better 'not knowing the feature' needs to be defined/considered carefully. In the context of SHAP it doesn't meant that $X_i = 0$ but it means that we do not *know* the value of $X_i$. (we still may know the distribution of potential values of $X_i$ or we could estimate this distribution based on the data)

In order to make a prediction, without knowing the value of $X_i$, one would use the expectation of the outcome when $X_i$ is unknown (we compute the expectation of the potential outcome over the known or estimated distribution of $X_i$). Using $X_i = 0$ is not a good way to make a prediction when $X_i$ is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Upvoted.